# When using Image Data Generator from Keras in Python, how much of the data per batch is augmented?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, keras, deep-learning

```
  datagen = ImageDataGenerator(horizontal_flip=True, rotation_range=60, zoom_range=0.2, rescale=1./255)

  trainGenerator = datagen.flow_from_directory('ClassWeightRatios/100fake90real/Training/', class_mode='binary', batch_size=50, shuffle=True)
```

How much of this data would be changed to have horizontal flips or be rotated by a certain amount etc.? Is there a way of controlling perhaps the percentage of data that is affected by this?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no control over the amount of data that is augmented. One of the main goal of the data augmentation is to provide new data that was never seen before by the model in each and every epoch. Data augmentation takes a batch of images and augments them with random transformations and provides the transformed images to the model for training. So, in each and every epoch, the model sees different images (as the transformations are random).

If you want to use data augmentation partially as you mentioned above, then use data `data augmentaion` to generate some percentage (for example 20%) and save those augmented images to your local where the original images are there. Then use 'flow_from_directory` approach during training. More details are at [keras website](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/). Thanks!